# Modify pattern perspective for an UIBezierPath

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

i'm working on a project where i need to tap over an image creating a closed UIBezierPath.
after the path has been closed i draw a pattern inside the path.
With a slider on bottom i can set the zoom level of the pattern that will fill the path.
i'm now working on the perspective distortion of the pattern, but i can't get it.

Pattern is created like this

```
UIImage *originalImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tegole.jpg"];
UIImage *scaledImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[originalImage CGImage]
                        scale:(originalImage.scale * _zoom)
                  orientation:(originalImage.imageOrientation)];
UIColor *patternImage = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:scaledImage];
[patternImage setFill];
[_path fill];
```

Does anyone have any suggesion on what's the better way to achive this ? 
i was looking at opencv.framework ? could this be a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

I have been doing something similar recently, but I am using NSBezierPath instead of UIBezierPath... though they should be equivalent. I wanted to fill the interior of a hexagon with a bitmap image. I am writing a computer board game with hexagon tiles.

I created a hexagonal path, as such:

```
    let path = NSBezierPath()
    let rads = CGFloat(Double.pi) / 180.0
    var p = NSPoint(x: scale*cos(30 * rads) + x, y: scale*sin(30 * rads) + y)
    path.move(to: p)
    p = NSPoint(x: scale*cos(90 * rads) + x, y: scale*sin(90 * rads) + y)
    path.line(to: p)
    p = NSPoint(x: scale*cos(150 * rads) + x, y: scale*sin(150 * rads) + y)
    path.line(to: p)
    p = NSPoint(x: scale*cos(210 * rads) + x, y: scale*sin(210 * rads) + y)
    path.line(to: p)
    p = NSPoint(x: scale*cos(270 * rads) + x, y: scale*sin(270 * rads) + y)
    path.line(to: p)
    p = NSPoint(x: scale*cos(330 * rads) + x, y: scale*sin(330 * rads) + y)
    path.line(to: p)
    p = NSPoint(x: scale*cos(30 * rads) + x, y: scale*sin(30 * rads) + y)
    path.line(to: p)

    path.lineWidth = 3.5
```

... I then simply added:

```
    path.setClip()

    let mainBundle: Bundle = Bundle.main
    imagePath = mainBundle.pathForImageResource("Swatch1.png")!
    let gSwatch1 = NSImage(contentsOfFile:imagePath)!

    gSwatch1.draw(in: path.bounds)
```

...and this draws the image "Swatch1.png" within the bounds of the hexagon path.

You can scale the image by changing the bounding Rect of the destination, but you can also apply any other transformation using NSAffineTransform's, etc.